# Как идентифицировать автора чат-бота?

Tags: telegram-bot, facebook, бот, telebot, chat

Как подтвердить **авторство** чат-бота в **Telegram** (**WhatsApp**, **Facebook Messenger**, **Slack** и т.д.)? Человек скидывает тебе только **ссылку** на него. Что надо сделать, чтобы удостовериться, что именно он его разработал?

**Пример ситуации:** разработчик скинул мне ссылку на популярного Telegram-бота, который называется `*Тут его название*`, но он его не делал, и он даже ему не принадлежит, как мне можно в этом удостовериться?

**Теперь обратная ситуация.** Профессиональный разработчик создал популярного чат-бота, какие у него есть способы доказать мне, что именно он его создатель?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попросите его добавить команду `/about`, которая в ответ будет присылать имя и фамилию разработчика, например

Comment: Как я смогу подтвердить, что этого разработчика зовут также, как будет написано в /about? Вдруг он притворяется им? Есть ли иные способы?

Comment: @СергейБерезовский попросите там написать, какую-нибудь кодовую фразу, например "бобры съели слона", любой бред, добавит - значит у него как минимум есть права на изменение того бота, о котором идет речь

Comment: А что если бот был создан популярной компанией, например, StepikBot (Telegram). Они же не могут ради меня создать команду и написать там кодовую фразу. Также эта же команда будет доступна не только мне, но и множеству других пользователей. Есть еще идеи?

Comment: 1. Если бот создан большой компанией, то авторство вроде как и так понятно / известно. 2. Попросите добавить команду `/about63454782364923674164872154781645789` - кроме вас ее точно никто не узнает.

Comment: Если мне надо будет проверить около 100 ботов, то каждого просить добавить такую команду будет не сильно хорошо, хотя это возможно. Да и кто я такой, что их об этом просить. Допустим, что все 100 разработчиков ботов добавят ее, но можно ли как-нибудь автоматизировать этот процесс? Чтобы я не заходил лично на каждого бота и не писал эту команду, а просто посылал какой-нибудь запрос? Может есть другие более хитрые способы?

Comment: @СергейБерезовский , есть, напишите бота сами

Comment: Дело не в том, что мне нужен бот или кто-то должен мне его написать, а я никому не доверяю. Мне просто нужно проверить авторство бота. Как может человек подтвердить, что бот принадлежит ему. Например, Василий Пупкин написал мне в VK про своего Telegram бота. В лучшем случае, в нем будет написано: "Автор: Василий Пупкин". Вроде бы все достоверно и там и там написано "Василий Пупкин". Но, ведь, я также могу создать VK, назваться там как Василий Пупкин и написать, что его бот является моим. В нем же ведь написано "Автор: Василий Пупкин". В этом и состоит мой вопрос, как идентифицировать автора.

Comment: @СергейБерезовский а какая разница кто автор если Вы получили то, что Вам нужно (бота). Оратитесь в фирму(к фрилансеру), составьте договор подряда, в чем проблема?

Comment: @СергейБерезовский если не секрет, какой фукнкционал Вам необходим?

Comment: Вы не поняли суть примера. Представьте, что кто-то залил на популярный сайт вашего бота. И получает какое-то вознаграждение, за то, что его активно просматривают, он пользуется популярностью. Как вы можете доказать админу сайта, что это ваш бот, а тот, кто его залил на сайт - самозванец. Если вы это докажете, то он будет залит от вашего лица, а это значит, что теперь вы сможете получать эти плюшки. Явно он не будет переходить в чат к вашему боту и писать определенную команду, из-за кучи подобного рода заявок. Как ему понять, что именно вы являетесь настоящим автором, а тот человек самозванец?

Comment: @СергейБерезовский, так связаться с админом этого сайта и любым способом выше доказать, что этот бот ваш. Если захочет - и команду напишет, а нет, так хоть "звезду с неба достань" - не захочет проверять.

Comment: А если у него сотни таких заявок? Ему надо будет лопнуть, чтобы всех проверить. Каким способом он может все это автоматизировать, чтобы проверка авторства не имела слишком много действий, была простой, как для админа, так и для автора бота. Какие действия они должны выполнить? Платформы могут быть самые разные, не только Telegram. Также, я думаю, что большая компания, которая разработала бота не будет добавлять лишнюю команду, только из-за его верификации на малознакомом сайте, особенно если она иностранная. Надо найти более простой способ.

Comment: @СергейБерезовский добавить условие для публикации команда /author которая вываливает скан паспорта/линк вконтакте/ номер телефона для связи/ адрес проживания

Comment: @СергейБерезовский любая компания будет выполнять все пункты тз